# get the proper posts displayed

Tags: python, django, django-views

On my site the users can add posts, and search for the posts. 
I have also just made it possible for the users to add words(interests) and they gets displayed below the form. 
The words/interests should each be a link, which displays the clicked on interest post matches. I want it too work similar to the search query, so that it display all the post which have that word(the interest) in them. So for instance if a word is batman and is clicked on, it should display all the posts with the word 'batman' in. I was inspired by the search view, and tried to replicate it, but it don't display any posts?

Its the view function which is not right.

views.py

```
def interest_posts(request):
    interest = Interests.objects.all()
    try:
        q = request.GET.get('q', 'interest')
    except:
        q = False

    if q:
        k = q.split()
        if len(k) >= 2:
            posts = []
            for i in k:
                wall = Posts.objects.filter(post__icontains=i).distinct()
                for word in wall:
                    if word not in posts:
                        posts.append(word)
        else:
            posts = Posts.objects.filter(post__icontains=q)

    return render_to_response("posts/interests.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

interests.html

```
{% for post in posts %}

        <div class='well' id='post_div'>          

        <h5>{{ post }}</h5>

        </div>

    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think it'll work if you change:

`{{ post }}`

to:

```
{% for p in post %}
    {{ p.title }}     #or p.content, p.whatever
{% endfor %}
```

Edit: [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3457661/alex) caught a reading error on my part. I did not see that you were already iterating over your posts at the top of interests.html, and you of course do not need to iterate through a second time. Ignore the additional for loop and just try changing `{{ post }}` to `{{ post.something }}` - sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I could be wrong, but are you sure you want to iterate over `post`? He's already iterating over `posts` above that, so `post` would be an item in `posts`.

Comment: I completely missed the {% for post in posts %} at the top of the interests.html file. Thanks for pointing that out. I think it's just a matter of telling the template what aspect of `post` to display rather than just sticking the whole object into the template. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: That is not the problem. But thanks though. The approach in the .html works fine on my search.html. I am pretty sure it is the view there is something wrong with :P